# How to obtain the inverse of a matrix while solving an equation?

Tags: matrix, matrix-decomposition, convolution

Given a matrix $A$, let us assume there is a equation:
$Ax = b$

To solve for $x$, we can write:

$x = A^{-1} b$

---

One way to obtain the inverse of A is by single value decomposition:

Decomposition of $A$: $US(V^T)$, where $S$ is a diagonal matrix of singular values.

---

Therefore:

$Ax=b$

$US(V^T)x=b$

$x=(VW(U^T))b$, where $W=1/S$ along the diagonals.

---

Is there any other way instead of SVD to find the transpose of $A$.

Comment: If it's invertible, you can augment A with an identity matrix and then put A into row reduced echelon form though Gaussian Elimination  applying each operation to the augmented matrix.  Once in reduced echelon form, the identity matrix will be the inverse.  You can use LU decomposition too.  

Your question is confusing.  Are you trying to find the inverse or the transpose or both?

Comment: And I'm not sure what you mean by "in an equation setting."  Finding an inverse of a matrix is no different than finding one "in an equation setting."  An inverse in an inverse.

Comment: @Analyst1 I changed the title. Basically, what I am asking is while solving the equation (i.e., obtain x), I need to have the inverse of A. And instead of using single value decomposition, is there any other representation that I can use to solve the equation.

Comment: Why did you change the title then?  You have "Is there any other way instead of SVD to find the transpose of A."  You can use Gaussian Elimination to do what you are asking.

Comment: You *never, never, never* want to explicitly calculate an inverse of a matrix. It's slow, and it can go *horribly* wrong numerically. To solve an equation, use [Gaussian Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), which is covered in any elementary Linear Algebra textbook. To transpose a matrix, simply exchange elements, or indices - this is just a question of data structures.

Comment: @Analyst1 Thanks for classifications. In addition to Gaussian Elimination, what are other methods?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks! Any other method suggested?

Comment: Why don't you tell us why the methods suggested won't work for you.  There are many, many methods.  Too many to list probably.  And you still haven't made it clear what you are trying to do with the transpose.  How can it get any easier than elementary operations of moving elements around in a matrix to transpose it?  This is easily accomplish with, say, a double for loop in a simple computer program.

Comment: @Analyst1 I want to get a list of methodology that can find the inverse. If possible, can you make a list of methodology? Thanks.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question of why.  Do you not have access to a library?

Comment: @Analyst1 I am doing research and want to know this area more. I want to see what is existing and see if I can improve on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are lots of way to solve the linear equation problem based on matrix decomposition. For equation $Ax=b$, there are LU decomposition and QR decomposition as well. For example, when using LU decomposition $ X = LU $, you can perform forward substitute with $L$ then backward substitute using $U$. If you want use QR decomposition, $Ax=b$ means $QRx = b$ and get the result as $x = bQ ^ T R ^ {-1} $.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any other ways?

Comment: I do not aware any other computational method for computing the inverse of a matrix. You mean manually?

Comment: YuZhang, according to @Analyst1, there are many other ones, but I am not sure what are those though